# Attempt to build example library fails in domino designer 9.0 with sparse info on error

Tags: java, api, xpages

I followed the example given at http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_an_XPages_Library within IBM Domino Designer 9.0.1. All three sample projects import without an error. I ensured that the dependencies are set.

When I try to build the update site, all I get is "BUILD FAILED: java.lang.NullPointerException"

I'm not sure where to go from here to find out what the actual cause of the error is. I also tried to create a separate Plug-In project with my own sample control from scratch, ended up with the same problem. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to provide the sources you created, otherwise it is anybody's guess.

Comment: Hi Stephan, it's basically the sample projects. Here is the current state of the projects I have in my designer: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8mp1c1j41cbzyh/sampleProjects.zip

Comment: Java is 6.0 - and try Eclipse. Domino Designer might have unmet dependencies. In Eclipse point to the Domino JVM

Comment: Indeed, not doing it in designer did the trick. Thanks Stephan. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is build with Eclipse as far as I remember. Might not work in Domino Designer which is based on an ancient version of Eclipse. I just checked... I have a number of plug-ins that were developed in Domino Designer. On possibility are the builders. An XPages project looks like this:
[image: Builders required for an XPages project]
while the builder for a plugin-project (in Domino Designer) looks like this:
[image]
So something might be broken in your installation of Domino Designer. Check the log and trace file for more detailed error messages.

Comment: I prefer the separate eclipse approach anyways. I just put together a simple custom sample control, built the updateSite in eclipse and successfully installed it in Domino Designer. The control works fine in my Notes environment. Thanks again.